# Both phrases are correct? Doesn't or not

Tags: negation

Are both phrases are correct? Doesn't or not.

> 1. It's important **doesn't** to arrive late.
> 2. It's important **not** to arrive late.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't is a contraction for does not. 
Don't arrive late.
He doesn't arrive late.
It is important NOT to arrive late.

But in English this would be turned around the other.

It is important TO ARRIVE on time. Or, to not be late. A person *is* late, not *does* late.

Answer (score 0):

Number one is incorrect.

Number two is correct.

Notice that statement two puts "not" in the right place.  The other thing that might be said is that statement two is not how most people would express that idea.  It is more common to say:

**"It's important to be on time."

"It is important to arrive on time."**